# return true if mysql update statement excute and false when no row was updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a mysql update statement but it return true when rows are updated and when no row is updated.

i want to knw if row was altered or  not.

here is my query:

```
$q=mysql_query("UPDATE results set marks='$mark' and total='$total'
                 where result_id='$rid'");


if($q){
      echo 'rows updated';
   }
else{
      echo 'No row was updated';
   }
```

it always print the "row updated " message, whether no record updated or not.

any help plz?

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows()`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) instead.

From the documentation:

> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, **UPDATE**, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

Note that`mysql_*` functions are deprecated -- I recommend you switch to [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead (and start using parameterized queries, to be safe from [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php))

Answer (score 0):

First, the proper syntax is:

```
UPDATE results
    set marks='$mark', total='$total'
    where result_id='$rid';
```

You might want to phrase it as:

```
UPDATE results
    set marks='$mark', total='$total'
    where result_id='$rid' and marks <> '$mark' and total <> '$total';
```

I think different versions of MySQL differ on whether or not they report a selected row changing, even when the new versions of the values are the same as the old values.